# url rewrite .htaccess : rewrite 2 pages with same rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so , i want your help 
I'm trying to rewrite 2 pages in that way

```
www.mydomain.com/page1.php?id=52
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com/52/
```

and another page2.php to much like this
www.mydomain.com/page2/id

I did so many research and i found this rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page1.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ users.php?id=$1
```

but when i tested this rule
if i worte in the url `www.mydomain.com/page2/id`  it play nice but i can't get the id variable throw php (`$_GET`)
if i remove page2 from the url (`www.mydomain.com/id`) it gave me page1

so, is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

> so, is it possible to do that ?

Your patterns look exactly the same except there is a trailing slash with one and no trailing slash with the other.

So whatever this "id" is, it matches the first rule, `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$` if it doesn't have a trailing slash, but matches the second rule, `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$` if it does have a trailing slash. That means:

```
www.mydomain.com/52/
```

rewrites to: `users.php?id=52`, and

```
www.mydomain.com/52
```

rewrites to: `page1.php?id=52`.

Now, if you want to make it so it works for both with or without the trailing slash, it's impossible. There's no difference between what 52 matches. For example, if you have this URL:

```
www.mydomain.com/1234
```

Is that for `page1.php`? or `users.php`? Both patterns are exactly the same, thus the first rule always matches and the second rule is always ignored.

Comment: ok....i see now ...so any idea how to fix that ? can i for exemple put one of the 2 pages in a folder and apply to it specific .htaccess ? otherwise any idea ? sorry, i don't know anything about url rewrite:( thank you so much "Jon Lin" for your answer ..i appreciate it

Comment: @ManarMiroo 1 htaccess per folder, you can't have it apply only to 1 page. Only way to fix it is to make the URL look different from each other.